# what is the compatible in memory db for azure cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am integrated my spring boot application with azure CosmosDB-SQL API and for integration test cases i want to use in memory database but trying with H2 in memory it's not working

Answer (score 2):

In my previous project I used `CosmosDB` and `MongoDriver`. In the integration test I had to use in-memory DB so I used [Mongo2Go](https://github.com/Mongo2Go/Mongo2Go). It has worked really good.

Comment: Do you know if this has a java equivalent?

Comment: @aemorales1 I am not sure but what a bout this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21  The downside of this approach is you have to install something on the local machine.

Comment: Thanks! I've started using test containers. Works for my needs.
https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/

Comment: @peymangilmour how did you use CosmosClient with Mogo2Go? i am facing error "only https schemes are allowed"

Comment: @Gurpreet I use currently MongoDB.Driver version 2.13.0 and Mongo2Go version 2.2.16 in our integration test project. When you start Mongo2Go, Does the URL have Https?

Comment: @peymangilmour no it starts with mongodb://localhost

Comment: @Gurpreet Probably using MongoClient is the key point. If you use Azure DevOps, please look at this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd

Comment: @Gurpreet The other approach would be creating docker compose for both your application and container based-CosmosDB. Run it in your pipeline first and then run the integration test.

Answer (score 0):

**Extended answer : For a NoSQL cosmosDb, there is none.** , i.e. there is no class library letting you instantiate a noSQL CosmosDb in memory for tests purposes, like you would instantiate, let's say, a SQL server db entirely in-memory.

Howerver, like the comments say, **you can run a "CosmosDb emulator" on a machine of your choice,** and make your code use it as a fake CosmosDb.

That implies:

- that you can install that emulator on your own machine if you run your test code locally,

OR

- that you can devise a deployment strategy to a **container** running that emulator (Docker or similar) so that this emulator can be used, for example, in your CD/CI pipeline in case it has a testing step before deployment.